# problem with samba

Tags: samba

I recently installed samba and the computer gave an error message saying that samba could not be installed... after that the same error message came for anything that i installed...
pl. help I'm very new to Ubuntu...

the error message when Itried it again

```
sudo apt-get install samba smbfs
[sudo] password for simon: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
samba is already the newest version.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cifs-utils keyutils
Suggested packages:
  winbind
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cifs-utils keyutils smbfs
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 103 kB of archives.
After this operation, 360 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main cifs-utils i386 2:5.1-1ubuntu2 [65.2 kB]
Get:2 htp://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main keyutils i386 1.5.2-2 [34.1 kB]
Get:3 htp://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main smbfs i386 2:5.1-1ubuntu2 [3,264 B]
Fetched 103 kB in 2s (45.0 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package cifs-utils.
(Reading database ... 236601 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking cifs-utils (from .../cifs-utils_2%3a5.1-1ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package keyutils.
Unpacking keyutils (from .../keyutils_1.5.2-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package smbfs.
Unpacking smbfs (from .../smbfs_2%3a5.1-1ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up samba4 (4.0.0~alpha18.dfsg1-4ubuntu2) ...
Unknown parameter encountered: "remote announce"
Ignoring unknown parameter "remote announce"
Unknown parameter encountered: "remote browse sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "remote browse sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "printcap name"
Ignoring unknown parameter "printcap name"
Unknown parameter encountered: "load printers"
Ignoring unknown parameter "load printers"
Unknown parameter encountered: "cups options"
Ignoring unknown parameter "cups options"
Unknown parameter encountered: "printing"
Ignoring unknown parameter "printing"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest account"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest account"
Unknown parameter encountered: "max log size"
Ignoring unknown parameter "max log size"
Unknown parameter encountered: "username level"
Ignoring unknown parameter "username level"
Unknown parameter encountered: "unix password sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "unix password sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "os level"
Ignoring unknown parameter "os level"
Unknown parameter encountered: "logon drive"
Ignoring unknown parameter "logon drive"
Unknown parameter encountered: "logon home"
Ignoring unknown parameter "logon home"
Unknown parameter encountered: "logon path"
Ignoring unknown parameter "logon path"
Unknown parameter encountered: "logon script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "logon script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "wins proxy"
Ignoring unknown parameter "wins proxy"
Unknown parameter encountered: "preserve case"
Ignoring unknown parameter "preserve case"
Unknown parameter encountered: "short preserve case"
Ignoring unknown parameter "short preserve case"
Unknown parameter encountered: "client use spnego"
Ignoring unknown parameter "client use spnego"
Unknown parameter encountered: "client schannel"
Ignoring unknown parameter "client schannel"
Unknown parameter encountered: "server schannel"
Ignoring unknown parameter "server schannel"
Unknown parameter encountered: "nt pipe support"
Ignoring unknown parameter "nt pipe support"
Unknown parameter encountered: "allow trusted domains"
Ignoring unknown parameter "allow trusted domains"
Unknown parameter encountered: "enable spoolss"
Ignoring unknown parameter "enable spoolss"
Unknown parameter encountered: "follow symlinks"
Ignoring unknown parameter "follow symlinks"
Unknown parameter encountered: "update encrypted"
Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
Unknown parameter encountered: "pam password change"
Ignoring unknown parameter "pam password change"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd chat timeout"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd chat timeout"
Unknown parameter encountered: "hostname lookups"
Ignoring unknown parameter "hostname lookups"
Unknown parameter encountered: "username map"
Ignoring unknown parameter "username map"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd program"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd program"
Unknown parameter encountered: "add user script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "add user script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "add user to group script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "add user to group script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "add group script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "add group script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "delete user script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "delete user script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "delete user from group script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "delete user from group script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "delete group script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "delete group script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "add machine script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "add machine script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "machine password timeout"
Ignoring unknown parameter "machine password timeout"
Unknown parameter encountered: "idmap uid"
Ignoring unknown parameter "idmap uid"
Unknown parameter encountered: "idmap gid"
Ignoring unknown parameter "idmap gid"
Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind use default domain"
Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind use default domain"
Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind cache time"
Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind cache time"
Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind trusted domains only"
Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind trusted domains only"
Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind nested groups"
Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind nested groups"
Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind nss info"
Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind nss info"
Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind refresh tickets"
Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind refresh tickets"
Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind offline logon"
Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind offline logon"
Unknown parameter encountered: "valid users"
Ignoring unknown parameter "valid users"
Unknown parameter encountered: "writable"
Ignoring unknown parameter "writable"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "public"
Ignoring unknown parameter "public"
Unknown parameter encountered: "locking"
Ignoring unknown parameter "locking"
Unknown parameter encountered: "writable"
Ignoring unknown parameter "writable"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "public"
Ignoring unknown parameter "public"
Unknown parameter encountered: "locking"
Ignoring unknown parameter "locking"
Unknown parameter encountered: "writable"
Ignoring unknown parameter "writable"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "public"
Ignoring unknown parameter "public"
Unknown parameter encountered: "create mode"
Ignoring unknown parameter "create mode"
Unknown parameter encountered: "locking"
Ignoring unknown parameter "locking"
Unknown parameter encountered: "writable"
Ignoring unknown parameter "writable"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "public"
Ignoring unknown parameter "public"
Unknown parameter encountered: "locking"
Ignoring unknown parameter "locking"
Unknown parameter encountered: "admin users"
Ignoring unknown parameter "admin users"
Unknown parameter encountered: "writeable"
Ignoring unknown parameter "writeable"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "locking"
Ignoring unknown parameter "locking"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "use client driver"
Ignoring unknown parameter "use client driver"
Unknown parameter encountered: "printing"
Ignoring unknown parameter "printing"
Unknown parameter encountered: "print command"
Ignoring unknown parameter "print command"
Unknown parameter encountered: "lpq command"
Ignoring unknown parameter "lpq command"
Unknown parameter encountered: "lprm command"
Ignoring unknown parameter "lprm command"
Unknown parameter encountered: "remote announce"
Ignoring unknown parameter "remote announce"
Unknown parameter encountered: "remote browse sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "remote browse sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "printcap name"
Ignoring unknown parameter "printcap name"
Unknown parameter encountered: "load printers"
Ignoring unknown parameter "load printers"
Unknown parameter encountered: "cups options"
Ignoring unknown parameter "cups options"
Unknown parameter encountered: "printing"
Ignoring unknown parameter "printing"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest account"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest account"
Unknown parameter encountered: "max log size"
Ignoring unknown parameter "max log size"
Unknown parameter encountered: "username level"
Ignoring unknown parameter "username level"
Unknown parameter encountered: "unix password sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "unix password sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "os level"
Ignoring unknown parameter "os level"
Unknown parameter encountered: "logon drive"
Ignoring unknown parameter "logon drive"
Unknown parameter encountered: "logon home"
Ignoring unknown parameter "logon home"
Unknown parameter encountered: "logon path"
Ignoring unknown parameter "logon path"
Unknown parameter encountered: "logon script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "logon script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "wins proxy"
Ignoring unknown parameter "wins proxy"
Unknown parameter encountered: "preserve case"
Ignoring unknown parameter "preserve case"
Unknown parameter encountered: "short preserve case"
Ignoring unknown parameter "short preserve case"
Unknown parameter encountered: "client use spnego"
Ignoring unknown parameter "client use spnego"
Unknown parameter encountered: "client schannel"
Ignoring unknown parameter "client schannel"
Unknown parameter encountered: "server schannel"
Ignoring unknown parameter "server schannel"
Unknown parameter encountered: "nt pipe support"
Ignoring unknown parameter "nt pipe support"
Unknown parameter encountered: "allow trusted domains"
Ignoring unknown parameter "allow trusted domains"
Unknown parameter encountered: "enable spoolss"
Ignoring unknown parameter "enable spoolss"
Unknown parameter encountered: "follow symlinks"
Ignoring unknown parameter "follow symlinks"
Unknown parameter encountered: "update encrypted"
Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
Unknown parameter encountered: "pam password change"
Ignoring unknown parameter "pam password change"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd chat timeout"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd chat timeout"
Unknown parameter encountered: "hostname lookups"
Ignoring unknown parameter "hostname lookups"
Unknown parameter encountered: "username map"
Ignoring unknown parameter "username map"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd program"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd program"
Unknown parameter encountered: "add user script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "add user script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "add user to group script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "add user to group script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "add group script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "add group script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "delete user script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "delete user script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "delete user from group script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "delete user from group script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "delete group script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "delete group script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "add machine script"
Ignoring unknown parameter "add machine script"
Unknown parameter encountered: "machine password timeout"
Ignoring unknown parameter "machine password timeout"
Unknown parameter encountered: "idmap uid"
Ignoring unknown parameter "idmap uid"
Unknown parameter encountered: "idmap gid"
Ignoring unknown parameter "idmap gid"
Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind use default domain"
Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind use default domain"
Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind cache time"
Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind cache time"
Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind trusted domains only"
Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind trusted domains only"
Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind nested groups"
Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind nested groups"
Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind nss info"
Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind nss info"
Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind refresh tickets"
Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind refresh tickets"
Unknown parameter encountered: "winbind offline logon"
Ignoring unknown parameter "winbind offline logon"
Unknown parameter encountered: "valid users"
Ignoring unknown parameter "valid users"
Unknown parameter encountered: "writable"
Ignoring unknown parameter "writable"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "public"
Ignoring unknown parameter "public"
Unknown parameter encountered: "locking"
Ignoring unknown parameter "locking"
Unknown parameter encountered: "writable"
Ignoring unknown parameter "writable"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "public"
Ignoring unknown parameter "public"
Unknown parameter encountered: "locking"
Ignoring unknown parameter "locking"
Unknown parameter encountered: "writable"
Ignoring unknown parameter "writable"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "public"
Ignoring unknown parameter "public"
Unknown parameter encountered: "create mode"
Ignoring unknown parameter "create mode"
Unknown parameter encountered: "locking"
Ignoring unknown parameter "locking"
Unknown parameter encountered: "writable"
Ignoring unknown parameter "writable"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "public"
Ignoring unknown parameter "public"
Unknown parameter encountered: "locking"
Ignoring unknown parameter "locking"
Unknown parameter encountered: "admin users"
Ignoring unknown parameter "admin users"
Unknown parameter encountered: "writeable"
Ignoring unknown parameter "writeable"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "locking"
Ignoring unknown parameter "locking"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "use client driver"
Ignoring unknown parameter "use client driver"
Unknown parameter encountered: "printing"
Ignoring unknown parameter "printing"
Unknown parameter encountered: "print command"
Ignoring unknown parameter "print command"
Unknown parameter encountered: "lpq command"
Ignoring unknown parameter "lpq command"
Unknown parameter encountered: "lprm command"
Ignoring unknown parameter "lprm command"
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba4.postinst: 14: /var/lib/dpkg/info/samba4.postinst: /usr/share/samba/setoption.pl: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing samba4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
Setting up cifs-utils (2:5.1-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up keyutils (1.5.2-2) ...
Setting up smbfs (2:5.1-1ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
samba4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use samba4, you have samba installed.

use this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge samba4
```